# sending a nexmo sms to all numbers stored in the database with laravel

Tags: laravel

hi everyone I have a problem with my code I try to send a nexmo text to all the numbers in my database. When sending I have this error in my browser "Array to string conversion" and the error shows this line "  CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData "if someone can help me."

I tried to do a dd (' $ message ') and dd (' $ options') I get the values of my fields well but when sending I always have the same error. I tried to see the method implode () but no success.

```
    public function sendMsg(Request $request)
    {
        $message = $request->input('message');
        $options = $request->input('telephone');
        $encodeMessage = urlencode($message);


        $authkey = '********'; 
        $senderId = '******************';
        $route = 4;
        $postData = $request->all();

        $mobileNumber = implode(" ", $postData['telephone']);

        $arr = str_split($mobileNumber, '12');
        $mobiles = implode(", ", $arr);

        $data = array(
        'authkey' => $authkey,
        'mobiles' => $mobiles,
        'message' => $encodeMessage,
        'sender' => $senderId,
        'route' => $route
        );

        $url = "https://rest.nexmo.com/sms/json";
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt_array($ch, array(
        CURLOPT_URL => $url,
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
        CURLOPT_POST => true,
        CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => $postData
        ));

        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYpeer, 0);

        $output = curl_exec($ch);

        if (curl_errno($ch)) {
        echo 'error:' . curl_errno($ch);
        }
        curl_close($ch);
        return redirect('/create');
    }
```

Comment: What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: I use the version 5.7.13

Comment: How come you're not using the built-in notifications? https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/notifications#sms-notifications

Comment: With integrated notifications of Laravel I don't know how to send a sms to all users of my database. Can you help me?

Comment: Are phone numbers stored in the users table? If so what is the name of the field? Also, is the message a custom message each time?

Comment: Yes the numbers are stored in the user table. The field name is "phone" and the message will be personalized each time. In fact I need to use a textarea to enter the message and a checkbox to select all the numbers in my table.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To send a custom sms notification to all of your users, you could use Laravel's built-in notification system.

All of the information you will need to get started is in the [Documentation](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/notifications#sms-notifications) on Laravel's website.

To get started you would need to:

**Download the nexmo composer package**:

```
composer require nexmo/client
```

**Add the config nexmo config to `config/services.php` file**:

```
'nexmo' => [
    'key'      => env('NEXMO_KEY'),
    'secret'   => env('NEXMO_SECRET'),
    'sms_from' => 'your-nexmo-phone-number',
],
```

**NB** Please only change the `"your-nexmo-phone-number"` part in the code above. Do **not** replace `NEXMO_KEY` and `NEXMO_SECRET` in the above with your actual key and secret as they are going to be stored in the `.env` and the value passed to the `env()` helper function will need to match the key in the `.env`.

> The **sms_from** option is the phone number that your SMS messages will be sent from. You should generate a phone number for your application in the Nexmo control panel.

**Add your nexmo api key and nexmo secret to your `.env` file**:

```
NEXMO_KEY=your-nexmo-api-key
NEXMO_SECRET=nexmo-secret
```

You should now be set up to actually send an sms with nexmo.

---

**Next, make sure your `User` model is set up to send the notification**

To do this make sure if is using the `Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable` trait e.g.

```
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable; // <--This bit

...

class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable; // <-- and this bit

...
```

Then add the following to your `User` model as well:

```
public function routeNotificationForNexmo($notification)
{
    return $this->phone;
}
```

This will let the notification system know what phone number to use for the user.

**Lastly, create a new notification class**

```
php artisan make:notification CustomSmsNotification
```

Go to the class (`app/Notifications/CustomSmsNotification.php`) and add change it to be the following:

```
<?php

namespace App\Notifications;

use Illuminate\Bus\Queueable;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\NexmoMessage;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Notification;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Queue\ShouldQueue;
use Illuminate\Notifications\Messages\MailMessage;

class CustomSmsNotification extends Notification
{
    use Queueable;

    /**
     * The message to send.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    public $message;

    /**
     * Create a new notification instance.
     *
     * @param $message
     */
    public function __construct($message)
    {
        $this->message = $message;
    }

    /**
     * Get the notification's delivery channels.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function via($notifiable)
    {
        return ['nexmo'];
    }

    /**
     * Get the Nexmo / SMS representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return NexmoMessage
     */
    public function toNexmo($notifiable)
    {
        return (new NexmoMessage)->content($this->message);
    }

    /**
     * Get the array representation of the notification.
     *
     * @param  mixed  $notifiable
     * @return array
     */
    public function toArray($notifiable)
    {
        return [
            //
        ];
    }
}
```

---

Your controller method would look something like:

```
public function sendMsg(Request $request)
{
    \Notification::send(User::all(), new CustomSmsNotification($request->input('message')));
}
```

Comment: @MDN993 Did this answer your question or do you still need help?

Comment: When I try to send a text I have this error "Class' App\ Http\ Controllers\ Notification 'not found"

Comment: the error shows this line Notification::send(User::all(), new CustomSmsNotification($request->input('message')));

Comment: My project is localhost that isn't the problem?

Comment: @MDN993 No, it shouldn't have anything to do with it being localhost. Did you definitely put the backslash in front of `Notification` (e.g. `\Notification`)?

Comment: Yes I just added it but now I have this error " Bad credentials "it's like the routenotificationfornexmo does not find the number stored in the table users.

Comment: @MDN993 **Bad credentials** says to me that you've not added the correct nexmo credentials in your `.env` file or  you've not added the correct send from phone number provided by nexmo in your `config/services.php` file.

Comment: I tried this code " Route::get('/', function () {
    $basic  = new \Nexmo\Client\Credentials\Basic('*******', '**********');
    $client = new \Nexmo\Client($basic);

    $message = $client->message()->send([
        'to' => '243898211405',
        'from' => 'Nexmo',
        'text' => 'Hello from Nexmo'
    ]);
    /*return view('welcome');*/
}); " it works, but with laravel notification it still doesn't work I don't know what's wrong is all ok

Comment: Do I have to install something other than nexmo client?

Comment: @MDN993 Did you put those credentials in the `config/service.php` file or the `.env` file i.e. if you do `dd(config('services.nexmo.key'), config('services.nexmo.secret'));` do you see you client key and secret?

Comment: yes I put the client key and secret in config/services and in .env.

Comment: 'nexmo' => [
        'key'      => env('********'),
        'secret'   => env('*****************'),
        'sms_from' => 'Nexmo',
    ],

Comment: .env file
NEXMO_SECRET=****************
NEXMO_KEY=***************

Comment: @MDN993 The `config/services.php` should not contain your nexmo key and secret. The `env()` helper function is used to resolve values from your `.env` file, the value passed to it should match a key in your `.env` file i.e. change the code in `services.php` back to  your `'key'      => env('NEXMO_KEY'),  'secret'   => env('NEXMO_SECRET'),`.